# How add сomments in my app on Ionic?

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

How better implement the possibility of comments (I meant that users would comment) in my application. Are there any plugins for this?

I did not try anything, because I don't know where to start. Here's an example: you have an application store, and on the page of each product users have the opportunity to comment (leave a review about the quality of the goods).

Comment: What is a `comment`? What did you find and why does it not make it?

Comment: @R. Saban  I meant that users would leave feedback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to you described above, I don't think you need any plugins currently.

At client side, in order to allow users to provide comments, just create a UI for users to fill comments, and then create a http request (see @angular/http) which submits the gathered comments to somewhere (eg:your can create a server to do so)

Answer (score 8):

Ionic is based on AngularJS; which is a Javascript framework.

Comments for Javascript are always using the same statements.

```
// before your comment
```

or `<!-- for your comments -->`

Comment: @S.Oleg: a volunteer takes interest in your question, takes the time to create an answer, and you criticize him? Seriously?

Comment: @Hovercraft Full Of Eels Maybe you misunderstood me, I did not criticize anyone

Comment: I'm just so dumb that this question is understandable only for me

Comment: @S.Oleg: your initial question was quite vague. After the edit, it's a little clearer, but you might want to provide more detail and more information about what searching you've done and what you've tried.

Comment: @Hovercraft Full Of Eels I did not try anything, because I do not know where to start. Here's an example: you have an application store, and on the page of each product users have the opportunity to comment (leave a review about the quality of the goods)

Comment: @Hovercraft Full Of Eels Maybe I'm not asking the right question, do you understand me?

Answer (score 1):

You want a plugin which should handle user comments and reviews.

It is totally code based, It does not have/require a plugin as such.

As comments/feedbacks/chats requires database, you need to write your own logic.

I am afraid there is no such plugin that could handle such senarios.

You can find [UI](https://github.com/nickplesha/ionic-threads) for that but you need to write login or use js help.

Let me know if you find such.